# Sling process child resources

Tags: aem, sling

Is there a way to access properties of a child resource using Sling API ? I know with JCR API it is possible to access child nodes. Sling does give a way to list Children. But

```java
Resource pageResource = resolver.getResource("/content/sitename/page/jcr:content");
ModifiableValueMap map = pageResource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class);
map.put("component01/propertyName","Changed Text");
```

doesn't work. This throws an 'Invalid Property' SlingException. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I believe its "" and not “” (quotes) .

Comment: The complete stack trace and exception message would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't work. This throws an 'Invalid Property' SlingException.

The quotes (“”) seem to be little fishy as I mentioned in the comment.

Try the following snippet .

You can fiddle around with these kind of requirements with the beautiful [AEM Fiddle by ACS Tools.](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/aem-fiddle.html)

```
Resource pageResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/sitename/page/jcr:content");
Iterable<Resource> childrenResources = pageResource.getChildren(); // Gives you all the resources representing direct children of /content/sitename/page/jcr:content 

for(Resource childResource : childrenResources){
    ModifiableValueMap mValueMap = childResource.adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class); // childResource should represent "component01"  .
    mValueMap.put("someProperty", "Some Value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The quotes are not the problem. It is just a copy/paste error when I was fiddling with Syntax highlighting in Stackoverflow. :)

Also the listChildren option will not work in my case as I want to dispatch the page resource, instead of child resource [1 call instead of multiple resourceDispatchers].

Comment: @Silican - what do you mean by "resource dispatcher"?